# GLMM when the dependent variable has three levels

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, multinomial-distribution

I'm trying to fit mixed models in R for data where the dependent variable is categorical with three levels (choices of True, False, Unsure). My plan was to fit three separate binomial mixed models (for True vs. False-or-Unsure, False vs. True-or-Unsure, Unsure vs. True-or-False) using glmer in lme4, and then draw conclusions about the impact of the fixed effects on each choice by looking at the separate models. But I have some questions about whether this is the best approach:

**Question 1**: Is the correct way to implement this method to fit *two* separate binomial  models (e.g. True vs. False, True vs. Unsure) instead?

**Question 2**: After fitting separate binomial models, does one need to somehow combine them into a single model in order to draw conclusions about the influence of different effects on the dependent variable? Or is it fine to (say) use `emmeans` for post-hoc comparisons on each of the binomial models separately?

**Question 3**: Is it important for the random and fixed effects to be the same for each binomial model? Having applied likelihood ratio tests to various candidates for each of the binomial models, it seems that the random effects that produce the best models differ in each case. E.g. the addition of random slopes for workers produces a significant improvement in the model for False vs. True-or-Unsure but not in the one for Unsure vs. True-or-False. So is deciding on a single set of effects part of the model-selection process, or can there be methodological grounds to expect different random effects for each of the binomial models (e.g. if workers' strategies differ when choosing False but not for other choices)?

**Question 4**: Are there reasons to instead fit a multinomial mixed model via other packages in R? I've heard that the `ordinal` and `MCMCglmm` packages allow this. My concern was that interpreting and analysing such a model would be more challenging for someone who's new to statistics.

**Update 1:**

In light of the comments and answer below, it looks like my original plan of fitting separate binomial models isn't great. I've tried using `ordinal::clmm()` and `mclogit::mblogit()`, but have had some problems with both options, which I summarise below.

**ordinal:**

- The model converges using the code `clmm(choice ~ A * B + (1|item) + (B|participant), data = targets)`. But I'm struggling to understand the coefficients in the summary. E.g., the estimate for level *a2* of fixed effect *A* reads -4.5560; does this mean that *a2* decreases the likelihood of a 'higher' choice? Even if this is right, I don't know how to interpret this with respect to my hypotheses. Some of my hypotheses concern the likelihood of Unsure (coded as 2) relative to False (1) or True (3); so what is the impact of a decreased likelihood of a 'higher' choice?
- I'm also confused about the threshold coefficients. The one for 1|2 reads -4.2262; so does this mean that there is a decreased likelihood of choice 1 relative to 2, calculated with respect to the model's reference level (which is presumably level *a1* of effect *A* with level *b1* of effect *B*)?
- The application of `emmeans` works fine. Presumably, the estimate for *a1 b1*-*a2 b1* (= 4.556) indicates that there is an increased likelihood of a 'higher' choice for *a1 b1* relative to *a2 b1*. But I again struggle to relate this to my hypotheses concerning the likelihood of Unsure.

**mclogit:**

- There are some problems with getting models that converge, perhaps due to incorrect syntax. The code `mblogit(choice ~ A * B, data = targets, random = ~1|participants)` works fine, but attempting to add a random slope or multiple random effects produces error messages. E.g., `mblogit(choice ~ A * B, data = targets, random = ~1|item + ~1|participants)` gives the error 'subscript out of bounds', and `mblogit(choice ~ A * B, data = targets, random = ~B|participants)` gives the error 'variable 'B' is absent, its contrast will be ignored' plus a failure to converge.
- The summary of the model that converges is easier to interpret than for clmm, since there are separate parts for 2 vs 1 and for 3 vs 1. E.g. for 2 vs 1, the estimate for *a2* reads  -1.4687; this presumably means that *a2* decreases the likelihood of choice Unsure (relative to False), which can be directly linked to my hypotheses about the likelihood of Unsure.
- Something goes wrong with the application of `emmeans` to the model that converges: all of the estimates are very small and all of the p-values = 1.

**Main question:** Should I use `ordinal` or `mclogit`, and how do I resolve the above queries for the advised package?

**Update 2:**

I've been pursuing the strategy of using `mclogit::mblogit()`. Most models now converge without errors when I use the code  `mblogit(choice ~ A * B, data = targets, random = list(~1|item,  ~B|participants), method = "MQL"`. I have two remaining problems: 1. attempts at comparing models by using likelihood ratio tests via `anova()` don't go smoothly (unexpected degrees of freedom are often reported and the p-value is sometimes absent); 2. applying `emmeans` to models continues to produce strange results (the p-values are all listed as either 1 or NaN). If anyone is familiar with `mclogit`, then please tell me how to fix these problems (I can give more details) or whether there is a better way to compare models and carry out post-hoc comparisons.

Comment: An ordinal model would not be appropriate. You could consider `nnet::multinom` but that doesn't allow for mixed effects.

Comment: Maybe I'll take that back. I suppose True-Unsure-False could legitimately be viewed as ordinal. In any case, I do think one model is better than three, and `ordinal::clmm()` seems like a viable choice for your needs. The "latent" mode in `emmeans` (the default mode) lets you interpret the post hoc results as if you had observed a continuous response.

Comment: Thanks for raising the point that the ordinal package shouldn't be used for non-ordinal categorical data, which I hadn't realised (perhaps the clue was in the name). But I'm concerned that my data can't legitimately be viewed as ordinal: my hypotheses predict that Unsure is more likely than either True or False in certain conditions, so I don't think it can be seen as an 'intermediate' option. If my outcome isn't ordinal, what is the best option for an analysis that allows for mixed effects?

Comment: I think I disagree. What makes something ordinal is that there is a logical ordering of the LEVELS, not of their PROBABILITIES. And true-unsure-false does seem to me to lie on a continuum of response options, at least in some contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend fitting 3 seperate models. This will result in a loss of statistical power, and the the models themselves will not be directly comparable since the random structures will not be the same. In  generalised linear mixed models, the fixed effects are condtional on the random effects.

The `mclogit` can fit multinomial logit models in their conditional logit and baseline logit variants with random effects:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclogit/index.html

Comment: The all-powerful brms can also be used to fit (Bayesian) multinomial mixed models, I think. https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it

Comment: Thanks, it does answer my question, insofar as I agree that mclogit is the most appropriate package for my purposes. It doesn't fully address my problems, for the reasons described in the second update to the question.